# Event handler in react is returning null inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 functions. The first function returns a Promise that finds the highest zIndex on the page. The second function handles the onClick. So when I press on an element, it loops through certain divs, finds the greatest zIndex, then adds 1.

This is the code:

```
  findHighestZIndex(elem) {
    return new Promise((res, err) => {
      if(!elem) console.log(err)

      let highest = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(elem))
      .map(a => parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(a).zIndex), 100)
      .filter(a => !isNaN(a))
      .sort()
      .pop();

      return res(highest);
    })
  }

  onStart(e) {

    let frame = e.currentTarget

    this.findHighestZIndex('react-draggable').then((res) => {

      if(res >= 0) {
        frame.style.zIndex = (+res) + 2
        console.log(e.currentTarget)
      } else {
        frame.style.zIndex = 1
      }

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('error')
    })

  }
```

`e.currentTarget` is returning null. If I store the currentTarget inside the variable it works, until you click the same element twice.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is my whole Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
import Router from 'next/router'


import {
  BrowserFrame, 
  DragHandle,
  BrowserContent 
} from './styles'

class DesktopBrowser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  findHighestZIndex(elem) {
    return new Promise((res, err) => {
      if(!elem) console.log(err)

      let highest = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(elem))
      .map(a => parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(a).zIndex), 100)
      .filter(a => !isNaN(a))
      .sort()
      .pop();

      return res(highest);
    })
  }

  onStart(e) {

    let frame = e.currentTarget

    this.findHighestZIndex('react-draggable').then((res) => {

      if(res >= 0) {
        frame.style.zIndex = (+res) + 2
        console.log(e.currentTarget)
      } else {
        frame.style.zIndex = 1
      }

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('error')
    })

  }




  render() {
   return (
      <Draggable 
        bounds="body"
        handle=".drag-handle"
        onStart={this.onStart.bind(this)}
        defaultPosition={
          {
            x: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].offsetWidth - 1000)), 
            y: Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].offsetHeight - 500)) 
          }
        }>
      <BrowserFrame>
        <DragHandle className="drag-handle" />
        <BrowserContent bg={this.props.content.image}>
          <button onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            Router.push(`/portfolio/${this.props.content.slug}`)
          }}>View</button>
        </BrowserContent>

      </BrowserFrame>
      </Draggable>
    )
  }
}

export default DesktopBrowser
```

Comment: Why are you returning a promise from `findHighestZIndex`? Isn't the logic synchronous?

Comment: @Tholle Should I not return it as a promise? Instead return the `highest` array?

Comment: Since the logic is synchronous you could just return `highest` straight away and use that instead of using a promise and making it asynchronous.

Comment: @Tholle Would that fix the even.currentTarget coming back null?

Comment: Most likely yes, since [React events don't work properly when used asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). You could alternatively try `event.persist()`, but you might as well make the synchronous logic work without the promise in my opinion.